# How big would a satellite need to be to block out the sun?

Tags: space-constructs, climate-change

I have a story idea that involves a human attempt to halt and reverse global climate change. The idea is a simple one - a satellite that partially blocks out the sun. The satellite is located at the L1 [lagrange point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) and is stabilised to always cast the most efficient shadow on earth.

The satellite would be similar to a solar sail with a surface area many square kilometers.

[image: Solar Sail]

Ideally, I would aim to block 1% (or less) of solar energy. It would only need to cool the earth by a fraction (say 0.1) of a degree per year.

This is where I need clarity.

- <strike>Would 1% be too much cooling?</strike>
- What would the size of the satellite need to be to block that much sunlight? 100 km square?
- <strike>Is there anything else I haven't thought of?</strike>

---

Edit: This question isn't about being visible from Earth. In the world I'm working on, it's not even noticeable from earth without high tech equipment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [How large does a spacecraft need to be to be visible from the surface of the Earth at 400 km altitude?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3768/29) will be helpful, **possibly even a duplicate,** if you just plug in your desired figures and turn the equations around. We know the angular size of the Sun as viewed from Earth, and you can pick an orbital altitude; given those, you can calculate how large it will need to be.

Comment: [Do you need it to be a satellite?](https://i.imgur.com/GxvdIrx.jpg)

Comment: Related:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/99095/is-it-possible-to-have-near-future-satellites-that-appear-to-rise-and-set-like/99107#99107

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How large does a spacecraft need to be to be visible from the surface of the Earth at 400 km altitude?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/how-large-does-a-spacecraft-need-to-be-to-be-visible-from-the-surface-of-the-ear)

Comment: I remember answering this before!  Let’s see… see [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/37866/885).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72026/discussion-on-question-by-coomie-how-big-would-a-satellite-need-to-be-to-block-o).

Comment: I disagree completely that any of the suggested related and/or duplicate questions actually are duplicates.  They're certainly similar, but not similar enough.  This question is basically asking, "if something is at the L1 point, how large would it need to be to cast a penumbra over at least 1% of the Earth's surface?"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**TLDR;**

**The equations:**

$$r_{B} = \sqrt{\frac{F}{2.46\times 10^{-14}}}$$
**or rearranging for**
$$F = r_{B}^{2} \times 2.46\times 10^{-14}$$

**Where $F$ is the fraction of light blocked ($F=0.01$ gives your $1\%$) and $r_{B}$ is the radius of your satellite in meters which will achieve this.**

For one percent reduction, using the equations above, we need a satellite of radius $6.376 \times 10^{5}$ m , or $637.6$ km - pretty big to say the least! (roughly the size of Alaska).

## The Maths

Initially you added a 'mathematics' tag onto this question - I'm assuming you wanted something more along the lines of a hard science tag (rather than asking about building a mathematical system as the tag is intended).

**Distance to $L_1$**

The [wiki for Lagrangian points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point#L1) gives this equation:

$$d_{E} \approx D \sqrt[3]{\frac{M_{E}}{3M_{S}}} $$

Where $d_E$ is the distance $L_{1}$ is from Earth, $D$ is the distance between the Sun and Earth and $M_S$ and $M_{E}$ are the masses of the sun and earth respectively.
Using:

$$D = 149597870700 \text{ m}$$
(This is [1 Au](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit), the average distance, so will change but the equation is already approximate)
$$M_S = 1.9885 \times 10^{30} \text{ kg}$$
$$M_E = 5.9724 \times 10^{24} \text{ kg}$$
As given by [the NASA factsheet](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/sunfact.html).

Giving us $d_{E} \approx 1.49656 \times 10^{9} \text{ m}$ or $1.5$ million kilometers.

Now lets look at what this means for how large a satellite you'll need.

The radius, $r_B$, of the Blocker projected onto the Earth gives a shadow with size $r_B^{'} = \frac{D}{d_{S}}r_B$ where $d_{S}$ is the distance the satellite is from the sun ($d_{S} = D - d_{E}$).

If we want to know the fraction, $F$, of light the satellite will block we can compare the areas of circles presented (the earth is actually a sphere so this won't be exact).

$$F = \frac{\pi r_{B}^{'2}}{\pi r_{E}^{2}} = \frac{(r_{B} \frac{D}{D-d_{E}})^{2}}{r_{E}^{2}} = r_{B}^{2} \times 2.46 \times 10^{-14}$$

Which you can use to calculate how much light you would block out for a satellite of a particular radius or rearrange to get the radius needed for a particular fraction ($r_{B}^{2} = \sqrt{\frac{F}{2.46\times 10^{-14}}}$ ).

Comment: I guess this is under the assumption that the sun is far away enough to be considered a point source? (I guess that's OK because the Lagrange point is so close to Earth, relatively speaking.)

Comment: @sanchises The distance between L1 and Earth is less than the distance between the perihelion and aphelion of Earth. That is to say, the change in relative angular size of the sun at L1 is less than the relative change in angular size of the sun between January and July here on Earth. That is to say, not much. I think point source is reasonable.

Comment: @Sanchises yes, the Sun is definitely far enough away to be considered a point source.

Comment: I hate to throw in a wrench but the radiation pressure from blocking 1% of all sunlight to earth is probably large enough to throw off the astrodynamics in the answer. I'm not sure it would be stable at L1. (For an order of magnitude though this answer is perfect.)

Comment: @RonJohn, long time ago there was an astronomic contest. One problem suggested was to determine the length of a shadow thrown by 10 meter tall column 20cm in diameter, when the Sun was 30 degrees above horizon (numbers are not exact). Now think a bit - why do you need to know the column diameter at all, if the Sun is a point source? Many people failed to give the correct answer.

Comment: @ZuOverture "*Now think a bit - why do you need to know the column diameter at all, if the Sun is a point source?*" Trick question: you don't!

Comment: @RonJohn, well, you may wish to do some calculations or you may join the failed group ) 0.5 degrees in astronomy isn't something you can easily handwave.

Comment: The story about column shadow was to show that all calculations in this answer after L1 distance, alas, aren't right, @Sanchises questioned them absolutely correctly. If the blocker size is less than ~14000km, there will be no umbra at all.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. L1 is approx 4 times farther away than the moon. During a total solar eclipse the moon doesn't even cut out 1% of total sunlight when you consider the entirety of the sunlit side of the Earth, yet you are suggesting an object much smaller than the moon would be adequate.

Comment: @ZuOverture Not having a dark shadow (umbra) visible on Earth would be a benefit, as that would have a lower impact on day-to-day life. What's at issue is: Does interposing something like this reduce the overall radiation delivered to the Earth? It does do that, by directing elsewhere the desired portion of the radiation which would have hit the Earth. Yes, to have an engineering-accurate number you definitely need to account for the Sun not being a point-source, not to mention needing to account for how far Sun-ward it needs to be from L1 to balance the force from the sunlight it redirects.

Comment: Having an umbra or not doesn't affect the percentage of energy blocked while all shadows (umbra and penumbra) are cast on Earth.

Comment: @Octopus, Moon size is ~3500km. 3500*4=14000km, so it _does_ seem right.

Comment: @Pere, why, it surely does. You can't use the assumption that Lio had used to avoid the necessity to integrate the blocking percentage function over the Earth surface, or you'll be wrong by several orders of magnitude. If you put real numbers in his final formula, you'll get 1% reduction with ~650km satellite. How is that correct, if 3500km moon four times closer blocks less during eclipses?

Comment: @Octopus, 14000km match up with linear size of an object at L1 distance, that has the same angular size as the Moon for the Earth-based observer.

Comment: @Octopus, it does not appear in this answer, but the author's result of 637km can't be correct, because 14000km is _the minimum_ required for his resulting formula to have at least some sense. Solve the problem with column shadow, and you'll see why his assumption about point-sized Sun is wrong.

Comment: @ZuOverture I saw your comments but wasn't sure so I [put it to the people at Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/380697/amount-of-light-blocked-by-a-body-at-the-earth-sun-l1-point). Only one person got back to me about it but their answer seems to agree with the one here. Feel free to write your own though. I'm pretty confused either way at the moment.

Comment: At that size I wonder if the solar radiation would be enough to push it away from L1...

Comment: @SilverCookies Assuming the force due to solar radiation is constant you would just need to place the satellite somewhere where those forces are balanced.

Comment: @LioElbammalf indeed, but then it's no longer at L1, and will not follow the earth in its orbit, am I correct? I wonder if there is an artificial lagrange point that acts like L1...

Comment: @SilverCookies L1 is the point where the forces are balanced such that the satellite _will_ follow earth in its orbit. The calculation above balances the gravitational forces, the force due to solar radiation is small in comparison but I'm sure it is taken into account when actually placing a satellite rather than giving ball park figures on how large the satellite would have to be.

Comment: @LioElbammalf I understand what you are saying, but I suspect the force exercized by the solar radiation will be quite significant for an object with such a large area pointed at the sun

Answer (score 3):

The energy needed to produce such satellite and put it on orbit would deny the idea behind fighting with climate change.

I ignore the Lagrange point and just assume you want to block 100 km square (nothing much really, clouds are blocking much more). So you want to create a shadow that is 100 km by 100 km large. ISS is 400 km above the earth. Mir was 350 km. So let's say 300 km from earth.

$$\text{Umbral size} = 2*(b S - B s)/(S - B)$$

Where: $b =$ blocker size
$B =$ blocker distance (from Earth's surface)
$s =$ sun radius
$S =$ sun distance (from Earth's surface)
$\text{Umbral size}=100$

From this we have
$$(50-b)S=B(50-s)$$ so $$(50-b)149600000=300(50-695700)$$
Which give us around 51.39 km. 
To put that into perspective – ISS is 109 metres wide. 
Titanic was 269 metres long.

And to go further. You know why NASA use gold foil? Because it's the best in blocking radiation. But use the cheapest tinfoil on the market (also the lightest). One sheet of 3 square meters of 0.3 mm thick foil weight around 2,63 kg (assuming density 2.80 g/cm³, to switch to gold just use 19.32). 51 square kilometres would require to put 44710000 kg of just foil (so no mechanism to unfold it, hold it together, counter engines, extra fuel etc.)
Next perspective, the ISS weight 419455 kg. 106 times less than you would want to put up there. [ISS in numbers](https://www.space.com/8876-international-space-station-numbers.html)

Also this equation tells us that the 300 km from earth is not enough as you would need a lot of (wild guess, more than 100 times the ISS need) energy to counter gravitation and stay on the orbit.

Also you know how much aluminium we produced in 2016 *in the world?* 57600000 kg according to [www.world-aluminium.org](http://www.world-aluminium.org/statistics/). So 70 % of all the world production would be needed for your project.

With this you can see that the Lagrange point would need to be much further away from Earth. Which would, of course, require larger size and result in larger mass.

So to summarize – in your story, around fifth calculation your humans would realize they can't produce enough tinfoil or producing enough tinfoil and fuel to put the satellite would spike up the energy production of the whole world.

Which could be a nice story on itself. Humans try to stop global warming in the worst way possible. By producing least effective solution that use so much energy they speed up climate change to one year.

Comment: Consider using MathJax, as far as I know, it works here as well. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/121236

Comment: @Mołot thanks for the tip. I wondered how to do them.

Comment: My pleasure. I still have problems with it, but at least there is a manual :)

Comment: A few links wouldn't go amiss either. Not that I doubt the validity of your claims but I'm sure you had to look up the 2016 world aluminum production so including the link to show where you got it from wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: You could build it in space, using materials from asteroids, so your answer is invalid

Comment: @CallumBradbury You want to catch asteroids and mine them or keep them together in a flat formation? Why don't just use magic?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Mining asteroids is not comparable to magic

Comment: @CallumBradbury Magic is just science we cannot yet explain. Catching an asteroid and slowing it down to use it or mining on a flying one and then exporting materials from it and using them (even in their ore form) would require so much resources that omitting that requirement and just going straight to "mine the asteroids" is comparable to "with a snap of his finger he made food appear on the table"

Comment: *0,3 mm thick foil* That's not foil, that's sheet metal. Aluminium household foil is about 1/20th that thickness. That leaves you with only 5 ISS masses and 3.5% of a year's aluminium production, which doesn't seem to bad (considering it saves the planet instead of just letting astronauts play in space). Delta-V required for low earth orbit is about 9.4km/s; only an additional Delta-V of 3.77km/s is required to get to L1.

Comment: More perspective: the energy required to make the whole thing and put it in space using your thick sheet (I assumed 1GJ/kg,which I think is a generous estimate) is equal to [less than 4 days](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=44710000kg*1GJ%2Fkg%2F(1400W%2Fm%5E2*100km%5E2)) of solar radiation blocked by the device.

Comment: @Sanchises I used this thicknes because allu foil is not the best in folding and unfolding when you use household thickness. The radiation stopping power by Allu is one of the worst (compared to gold or silver). In this case I used it to just stop light.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY The James Webb telescope uses 100nm aluminium coating on 25µm kapton films. Gold is mainly used for its high emissivity (so that it doesn't heat up the spacecraft through conduction); it blocks radiation just fine if conduction is not an issue.

Comment: @Sanchises I was taking material tip from here https://www.geek.com/news/geek-answers-why-does-nasa-use-so-much-gold-foil-1568610/. But now I think, how much would that heat up?  There is no lives or equipment to save from extensive heat but how would such structure work with large hot sheets of metal?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I don't think it would be terribly difficult, given that this is how they do it in real life in the James Webb telescope (they add silicon to the hottest layer to protect it). You may have to do some maintenance every now and then, to apply some new coating, but I'm sure PVD works just fine in space (perhaps aided by solar winds...)

Comment: @Sanchises I was thinking more about material expansion. Even 100sq metres of allu would expand totally different than the poles it's attached to.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Magic may be science we cannot yet explain, however you're using it as 'science that would use a bunch of resources' - like I said, not comparable. Any solution to the OP will involve the use of resources, it is feasible that they would turn to asteroid mining to help solve their problem. It's not feasible that they'd turn to magic...

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Nothing a small slit every so-many meters won't fix. Try to think in solutions, not problems!

Comment: Gold foil has the big advantage of a high Taybor number.  It's quite reflective in visible light, but is basically black in far infra-red.  This means that it's a good radiator.

Answer (score 3):

Echo I was an early satellite made from aluminum coated mylar.  100 foot diameter for 159 pounds.  It was inflated with 33 pounds of powders that sublimed in vacuum.  This was done with 50's tech.  The film was 1/2 mil (12 microns) and the aluminum coating was .2 microns.

Using this tech a 59 km diameter sphere would take 270 million kg.  This ignores the extra gas required to inflate a larger sphere.  (Volume of gas goes up with the cube, while the area goes up with the square of diameter.

I suspect an easier way would be to build induction catapults on the surface of the moon. and fire bags of rocks into L1, similarly to what G. Harry Stine proposed for this book "The Third Industrial Revolution. at that point you want to process them into a powder and give them a very slight electrical charge to keep them from clumping.

Unfortunately L1 isn't stable, so you will need to continuously replenish it.  It may be better to give Earth rings, like Saturn.  This is a short sighted solution, as it puts a lot of crud in orbit.  Eventually we will want to industrialize the solar system, and having large quantities of orbital sand is a significant traffic hazard.

*Edit: Such a satellite has to be 1/10 the diameter of the earth to block 1/100 of the sunlight.  So instead of 60 km in diameter it has to be ~1200 km in diameter.  My answer is off by a factor of 20^2.  This is a non-trivial project.*

Comment: I personally like the option of using many small objects of this type as it has the possibility of achieving the objective with very low launch mass compared to other solutions and very low manufacturing costs when we consider the scale of the endeavor.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to think about this without all the math is to look at the projected path of any total solar eclipse.  Only a small swath of land is generally affected, which is why during the latest total eclipse visible from the USA, people were traveling to other states to be able to get better views.

That said, it will also depend on a combination of how big it is and how far away it is.  Your thumb can block out the sun... at least from your point of view.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding! This is true, but doesn't fully answer the question, so would you be able to [edit] your question to answer how big the satellite would need to be?

Answer (score 2):

No reason to build a giant anything. Simply spread a plate shaped cloud of minute particles at L1 that would then block the appropriate amount of earth bound radiation. I visualize a multi-nozzeled spinning emitter to cancel its own thrust. I trust it could be determined what the resulting expanding donut shaped (or a different shape?)  cloud's duration and hence effect would be. Of course it may take multiple releases over time to do the trick.

Comment: I have edited the post to fix spelling and clarify the question mark. It was confusing, at least to me, as to why the sentence seemed to stop and then have a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer to the 3rd question "Is there anything else I haven't thought of?":

Politics. Such a sunshade made of reflexive material makes an enormous weapon. Earth receives about $1.7\cdot 10^{17} W$ from the Sun, 1% of that is $1.7\cdot 10^{15}W$. If you can focus the reflexive area (say to an area of a big city), you'll get an equivalent of 20 Hiroshima explosions per second. In short, [Die Another Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Another_Day) on (enormous) steroids.

Now, who is going to control the sunshade? The UN?

Comment: Even better example: Professor Wernstrom's sunlight-reflecting mirror from the Futurama episode "Crimes of the Hot". Built for the exact purpose the OP describes (reflecting *40%* of the sun's rays to cool Earth), but a micrometeorite strike flips it round and turns it into a death ray.

Comment: @F1Krazy, a mirror flipped around remains a mirror...

Comment: Nowhere in the question it says anything about reflective. And on the image it is shiny, but flat. Seems like you are solving problem that's not even there, and it feels more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @L.Dutch, a flipped mirror may mean a difference between converging and diverging lenses.

Comment: @Radovan Garabik I'd say at the L1 point it would be getting a bit more energy 1% of the energy that makes it to Earth, as the energy any one point receives from the sun drops with the cube of distance

Comment: @ZuOverture, a mirror is a mirror. A lens is a lens. They are not the same.

Comment: @L.Dutch, well, glad you know it. Now imagine that you can focus light with mirrors, like in heliostat, instead of deflecting it by just moving the same mirror.

Comment: @ZuOverture, a mirror is placed between sun and earth to reflect light away from earth. flipping that mirror will still reflect light away from earth, it won't magically focus the light on earth.

Comment: @L.Dutch, you'll only need to move mirror a bit ahead or behind the Earth-Sun line, the distance may be less than Earth radius plus mirror radius. Do you think that's impossible?

Comment: @ZuOverture At Lagrangian points? Moving something out of L point and *keeping* it there requires so much fuel that it would be easier to just nuke your opponent, thank you.

Comment: @Mołot, yes, at L1. Don't you think that having a million square kilometer mirror at your disposal somewhat beats chemical rockets in terms of propulsion effectiveness?

Comment: @ZuOverture Nowhere in question it is said that this is a mirror. And you still need some source of energy to balance, rotate etc your sail. Not to mention putting it in the right orbit.

Comment: @Mołot, excuse me, I tend to forget that people here prefer to perceive everything literally. Read "reflective surface" instead of "mirror" if you prefer it that way. And forget about using foil surfaces for photovoltaics, that's definitely not possible. Also you can't use them as solar sails and rotate them to change the direction of thrust. Definitely no way.

Comment: @ZuOverture Show me how you put anything on fire using white paper. It's reflective all right, you know.

Comment: @Mołot Very good point. Satellite DXers are very well aware of the danger from white dishes, melted LNB's are not uncommon: http://www.nzdtv.com/forum/showthread.php?4944-Melted-LNB . And that's just around a m², not million times more.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík, nice example )

Answer (score 0):

**Use the moon**

Why build an giant satellite to orbit the earth at all? Extend from the moon itself! The same side is always facing the earth. Just make static structures that extend from the edges of the moon (as it is seen from Earth)

This reduces the amount of materials you need to transfer up into space to build such a structure, plus you can mine the moon itself for materials.

As the moon casts a bigger shadow on earth, global temperatures will drop on average. This causes minimal distruption to existing systems. The shadow is not being cast over the same spot on earth all the time. This merely extends the area covered during solar eclipses that are alraedy happening.

Comment: I'm not sure you read the question... OP's looking to block 1% of solar energy. Moving the Moon to a point where it would block only 1% of solar energy would be far more difficult than building a satellite.

Comment: Moon already already exists as satellite that casts a shadow on the earth. No need to move it from its existing orbit at all. Only need to extend it.

Comment: You would need to lock the orbit so that it was always between the Earth and the Sun, and you would need to push it out farther from the Earth so that it blocked _only_ 1% of the solar energy.

Comment: No need to lock the orbit. Extending a sail light structure from the moon would simply extend the duration and coverage of existing solar eclipses. So that on average, over an year, less sunlight reaches the earth.

Comment: @NatraxYN The moon passes between (but not necessarily blocking) the sun and earth every 28 days and at most blocks the sun for 100 minutes. Even if you could expand the moon to total eclipse every lunar month, you would only block 1/4 of one percent of the time. You'd need to expand the lunar radius x4 at least. This is not an insignificant project.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've edited to remove the 3rd question, "Is there anything else I haven't though of?", I feel duty-bound to suggest that, yes, there is. It's the moon. L1 is at about 1.5 million km, and the moon's orbital radius is about 380,000 km. In the long run the moon is going to perturb anything at L1, so your "stabilization" mechanism will need to be a lot more robust than you think.

Answer (score 0):

From: James Alexander Jules Tyson

To: Global Climate Change UN Conference

Subject:*Global temperature reduction via Solar ions attraction to designed anion particle absorbtion and dispersal satellite proposal  * by James Alexander Jules Tyson,
Christchurch New Zealand

THE SOLAR RADIATION IS MADE OF  CHARGED PARTICLES. CHARGED PARTICLES can be /are attracted or repulsed by negative or positive plates in a designed satellite placed in an   continuous heliocentric orbit between earth and the sun. The solar charged ions collected in the plates (using near infinite resistors to handle the trillions of Evolts required for ionic solar radiation to be absorbed ) can then be dispersed into spaces vacuum via controlled ion expulsion of the collected energy of the stored ions (ions would not need to be stored for long only enough to divert their path to the earths atmosphere negating the ions ability to offload energy i.e. IONIC infrared radiation and thus preventing heating of earths atmosphere. Modern fusion experiments using "Tomahawk" plasma container coils that hold enormous energy  charged plasma (up to temperatures of 100 Million degrees celcius) maybe 
considered for the technology in the aforesaid satellite to intercept and then safely release the solar radiation into space vacum via oppositely  charged repulsion plates towards the outside of the satellite.

This technology  idea (if viable) would considerably reduce the cost of the satellite
required  since size of the satellite to intercept the solar  would be of a reasonable size ( say the size of a modern hydroelectric dam  power plant only deployed into space).
the key is the idea of attracting and compressing the soLAR energy before dispersal and having effect of cooling the earth.

20/08/2019
James Tyson

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE, JamesTyson. The solar wind and solar flares are composed of charged particles. Solar radiation is mostly electromagnetic radiation. Offhand I don't know how much the solar wind heats the Earth's atmosphere. At a guess, not much. Otherwise the atmosphere would be gone by now. Launching a satellite the size of a hydroelectric dam power plant is beyond current space technology. An interesting fix, but I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve.