# Can a Lagrange point move relative to other forces acting on it

Tags: space-constructs, solar-sails

In [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102489/how-big-would-a-satellite-need-to-be-to-block-out-the-sun) recently asked question on a large, sun blocking object it is pointed out in the comments that there would be ~10e7 N of thrust from the sun due to solar wind.

My question is does there exist a point, similar to the sun-Earth Lagrange point, where the gravitational *and* the solar wind forces will cancel out and so the described object would remain stationary without the need for any (or at least very little) maintained thrust?

Comment: This sounds like a question for [physics.se] or [space.se], more than a question about building a fictional world.

Comment: Great places to put space stations are on-topic on this site; I think this should stay open.

Comment: Welcome to the Site!  This is something that probably  does belong over in Physics because I'm sure you can derive a specific formula for it.

Comment: This belongs over at physics but the answer (I believe) they'll give you is essentially: **No, the solar wind will only push radially but deviating from the radius of the lagrangian point will effect the object's orbit tangentially so it would no longer have the same orbital period as the Earth**.

Comment: I was torn between the change in question type and leaving it here as it relates to a world-building question. Thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: You are describing a heliostat. This is basically a solar sail where its area generates enough force to counteract the Sun's gravitation. There isn't necessarily a specific point where this exists, it more a matter of building the right device to accomplish heliostationary "hovering".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *single point* like that. Forces created by gravity and rotation are independent* from actual mass or shape of the satellite. That's why we can talk about such points, universally.

Force created by solar wind, light pressure and so on depends on the shape of your satellite, surface, how reflective surface is, and so on. Thus, at the same point it can be quite large for one satellite** and rather minuscule for another.

That said, you can replace some of centrifugal force with solar sail power, and do some maneuvering by changing sail's orientation. How far from Lagrangian points your point of balance would be depends solely on the design of your craft, and thus, indirectly, tech level available in your world. In theory, if material wouldn't be a problem, you could even have a stationary platform that does not circle around your star at all. Or even propel entire star system with [Shkadov Thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_engine#Class_A_(Shkadov_thruster)).

---

* With assumption that mass of the object in L point is irrelevant in comparison with Sun and Earth.

** We don't have a word for pseudo-satellites on forced orbits, so I'll just use closest word we have.